# Assign new variable created with mutate_ to a name that will be passed as a string in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I want to use strings with dplyr expressions and in particular I want to pass expressions as strings to mutate to create new variables and assign names to these variables that will be passed also as strings.

My code at this point is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

data(mtcars)

mutate_expr = "gear * carb"

mtcars %>% mutate_(mutate_expr)
```

The new variable is named here 'gear*carb'.  How I could give it the name 'gear_carb' passing the name to the dplyr expression as a string?

Comment: Don't store code as strings. It causes bugs which pop up far from where the mistake is. And as I told you in your last question, dplyr's `*_` functions are deprecated [in favor of tidyeval](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: @alistair  Sometimes I want to create dplyr expressions inside functions that depend on arguments that will be passed to the function.  I want to have control over the dplyr expressions through the arguments of the function in which these dplyr expressions are embeded.  How should I do that?  Can you provide examples?

Comment: Read the link. That's entirely what it's about. For a deeper dive, https://adv-r.hadley.nz/meta.html

Comment: OK.  Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

You now do this with [tidyeval](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html):

```r
library(dplyr)

mutate_expr <- quo(gear * carb)

mtcars %>% mutate(new_col = !!mutate_expr) %>% head()
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new_col
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      16
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      16
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       4
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       3
#> 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2       6
#> 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       3
```

If you *must* store the expression as a string, you can use `sym` instead of `quo` (really `rlang::parse_expr` in this context), but storing code as a character string is a bad idea.

Comment: The one case where I see the need to manipulate variable names as strings, is with Shiny inputs, where I indeed tend to use `sym` or `as.name` .

Comment: There's a big difference between storing names as strings and expressions as strings. The former is fine (that's what `names` returns!); the latter quickly becomes problematic.